# Query post for 'selected category' in archive.php

Tags: customization, templates, archives, link-category

I'm trying to figure out how to display a `'featured post'` on a selected category archive.

My website uses the category-based navigation for different types of posts (text only post-blog, and image only gallery post), and is driven by a single custom archive.php.

> - Homepage: http://example.com/portfoliography
> - Auto gallery: http://example.com/portfoliography.com/automotive
> - Architecture gallery: http://example.com/portfoliography/architecture
> - (... and so on)

They all uses a single `archive.php`, and it works wonderfully to display category-specific images. See the current code [here](http://pastebin.com/1vVrMF28)

**What I'd like to achieve is to**

> query for the latest post only for the selected category, and feature it on top of the thumbnails as a slideshow like the one from the homepage. <sup>*)</sup>

<sup>*) latest post in automotive for automotive category archive, latest post in architecture for architecture category, so on…</sup>

My beginner's hack from a few goolge search [can be seen here](http://pastebin.com/p4qXnDtN).

But the said code generates a slideshow using images from posts in every category.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to simply make a `category.php` template file, that way you're not jamming everything into one template with multiple query's and conditionals.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Category_display

It is unclear what you mean by "featured", do you want an url like `http://example.com/portfoliography/architecture` to have a select posts at the top? Or do you want the category page to feature certain categories above others?

Comment: That's right, I want a category archive to feature one (latest) post for each respective category.